# How to fully remove VLC Player?

Tags: command-line, apt, dependencies, vlc, software-uninstall

I installed VLC player, but now I want to be fully rid of it, so I typed in the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge vlc
```

And it told me that it had purged it, but then in Terminal when I typed in `vlc`, this was the output (although no GUI launched):

```
VLC media player 2.2.0-pre2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.0-pre1-15-g5178b24)
[0000000001f3bab8] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[0000000001f21118] core libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0000000001f21118] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[00000000020f66d8] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.2.0-pre2 Weatherwax
Command Line Interface initialized. Type 'help' for help.
>
```

And if I type in `help` I get a proper response from the program. And it also allows me to type in and execute any associated command.

So how can I fully remove VLC Player so that when I execute the command `vlc` it tells me that it does not know that command?

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`vlc` depends on `vlc-nox`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/vlc) which [installs the `vlc` command](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/amd64/vlc-nox/filelist) that you see. Remove it specifically, or use `autoremove`:

```
apt-get autoremove
# or
apt-get remove vlc-nox
```

Comment: I tried running the `sudo apt-get autoremove` command in Terminal, but that did not remove `vlc-nox`. But when I ran the command `sudo apt-get remove vlc-nox`, that did the trick! Thanks! :)

Comment: @Toroidal for some reason `vlc-nox` is probably marked as manually installed.

Comment: @Toroidal, did you `sudo apt-get update` before attempting `sudo apt-get autoremove` ?

Comment: @Sean Yes and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Isn't it better to do a `purge` rather than a `remove` if one wants to remove it fully?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda if you can point me to any configuration files that VLC keeps in `/etc`, sure.

Answer (score 10):

None of the above will actually remove all vlc packages, (usually 6-7). Better to do -

`sudo apt-get purge vlc-data`

Answer (score 7):

To remove a package and all its dependencies in one command, you can also directly pass the package name as argument to `apt-get autoremove`:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove vlc
```

If you prefer to purge the packages (to also clean up all configuration files), the way to go is this:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge vlc
```

However, this will not work in your case, because of the complex dependency tree of `vlc`. `autoremove` only removes automatically packages which *currently* have no installed reverse-dependencies. That means as long as there are other packages which may depend on `vlc`'s dependencies, they will stay. Those other packages are probably `vlc-plugin-*` packages which depend on `vlc` but get not removed with that first run yet...

However, if you keep firing `sudo apt-get autoremove` after that first line, `apt-get` should slowly start to realize that there's more to remove.

Comment: Ah, but in this case the dependency `vlc-nox` wasn't removed with `sudo apt-get autoremove` as you can see in the comments to muru's answer, so this wouldn't have really helped me in this instance...

Comment: @ParanoidPanda After trying it out myself, I think I found out that the answer to your problem is recursion and persistence. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run these commands.

```
sudo apt-get remove vlc
sudo apt-get remove browser-plugin-vlc

sudo apt-get purge vlc
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `aptitude`, a sometimes more intelligent alternative to `apt-get`.

If you run **`sudo aptitude remove vlc`**, it will detect possible conflicts that would result of removing `vlc` and suggests to remove all those other "hidden" dependencies which `apt-get` would have missed on the first run.

If you haven't installed `aptitude` yet, that can be done using `sudo apt-get install aptitude`.